# I am Trying to make it so that if a form field is left blank it will default to something I have set

Tags: php

OK so I have a php form where I am dynamically adding to a recordset. One of the fields is an image field. What I would like to do is when it is left blank I would like it to insert a default image. I would use and if else statement that said something like

```
   if(image==null){
        get(logo.jpg)}
     else post image
```

but I'm not exactly sure how to do this in PHP any ideas?

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Adventures (Image, Activity, Location, `Date`) VALUES        (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Image'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Activity'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Location'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Date'],`enter code here` "text"));


 mysql_select_db($database_Mat, $Mat);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Mat) or die(mysql_error());
```

this is the code for the form.

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` on $_POST and additionally check for string length:

```
if (!isset($_POST['image']) || strlen(trim($_POST['image']))==0) 
    $image = 'image.png';
else
    $image = $_POST['image'];
```

then add `$image` to the database.